# How do I output all collections with MongoDB in NodeJS (MongoDB Compass)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Able to output one object based on the filter below, but in MongoDB there are 500 objects, so how do I output all the objects inside the collection of the MongoDB? Already tried find(). But then I got something like this.

[image]

The objects in MongoDB looks like this:

[image]

```js
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db('database');
    const music = database.collection('music');
    const single = await music.find();
    console.log(single);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it like this:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true }); //Options are optional
const db = await client.connect().db();
const results = await db.collection('music').find().toArray();
console.log(results);
```

I think you were missing `toArray()`